# Hide document library from Quick Launch using JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am creating Hidden document library using SharePoint hosted App and i have to hide this hidden library from quick launch.

I used below code but it's not working.

```
function createDocumentLibrary() {
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    hostcontext = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, hostweburl);
    this.web = hostcontext.get_web();
    this.lists = this.web.get_lists();
    clientContext.load(this.lists);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, createDocumentLibrarySuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, createDocumentLibraryFail));
}
function createDocumentLibrarySuccess() {
    var listCreationInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
    listCreationInfo.set_title(libraryName);
    listCreationInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.documentLibrary);
    this.oList = this.web.get_lists().add(listCreationInfo);
    this.oList.set_noCrawl(true);
    this.oList.set_hidden(true);
    this.oList.set_onQuickLaunch(false);
    this.oList.update();
    clientContext.load(this.oList, 'RootFolder');
    this.newColumn = this.oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml("<Field Type=\"Text\" DisplayName=\"JSVersion\" Name=\"JSVersion\" />", true,
        SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
    clientContext.load(this.newColumn);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onDocumentLibraryCreated), Function.createDelegate(this, onDocumentLibraryCreationFailed));
}
function createDocumentLibraryFail(sender, args) {
    console.log("Error : Create Document Library From > createDocumentLibrary. " + args.get_message());
}
function onDocumentLibraryCreated() {
    console.log("onDocumentLibraryCreated: Library Creted");
}
function onDocumentLibraryCreationFailed(sender, args) {
    console.log("Error : Create Document Library From > createDocumentLibrarySuccess. " + args.get_message());
}
```

How can i achieve solution?

Comment: can you please add the complete function?

Comment: Yes,I added function.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine on my site. But you can try this after *listCreationInfo.set_templateType*

```
listCreationInfo.set_quickLaunchOption(SP.QuickLaunchOptions.off);
```

in place of

```
this.oList.set_onQuickLaunch(false);
```

[Reference link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee551488%28v%3Doffice.14%29).

Comment: Thanks for response but not working for me.

Comment: Is it visible in "recent"??

Comment: Yes still it is visible

Comment: You will need to remove recent from the quick launch.

Comment: But my requirement is to only hide that hidden library after creating as i told i am creating hidden library

Comment: Write a code to remove that node from quick launch. This should run after list has created.

Comment: I already used jQuery to hide and it's working in console but thing is that library is creating using SharePoint Hosted App